# on . change is not working in jquery latest version

Tags: jquery

`.on('change')` function is not working

Html Code

```
 <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
    <select class="form-control" id="pagesize">
        <option value="10">10 Results</option>
        <option value="20">20 Results</option>
        <option value="30">30 Results</option>
        <option value="40">40 Results</option>
        <option value="50">50 Results</option>
        <option value="60">60 Results</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
    $("#pagesize").on('click', function () {
        alert("tretr");
        var pagesize = $('#pagesize').val();
        alert(pagesize);

    });
```

click function is not working

Comment: are you trying to use [`change`](http://jsfiddle.net/nsazzry4/) or [`click`](http://jsfiddle.net/nsazzry4/1/)?  Both work in the fiddle examples.  do you have any errors in your console?  What is not working?

Comment: then where is your change event code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it has been updated, use it like :

```
$('body').on("click", '#pagesize', function(){
        alert("tretr");
        var pagesize = $(this).val();
        alert(pagesize);

});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/v68n1n37/1/)

Comment: Why you use event delegation in the context. Its not dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this)` for get current object reference and change the event to `.change()`

```
$("#pagesize").on('change', function () {
        var pagesize = $(this).val();
        alert(pagesize);
 });
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/v68n1n37/)

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/kdmLy5zg/

```
With jQuery version 1.11.0
```